# Railsで自動的に反映されるはずのCSSが反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsではstylesheetsディレクトリ配下にapplication.cssがあればそれだけで自動的に反映されると言われますが、全く反映されません。何が問題ですか？

特にこれといったエラーは全くありません。
ちなみにHTMLは面倒くさいのでERBじゃなくて普通のHTMLです。
もちろん個別じゃなくてviewごとのHTML全体に反映するapplication.cssを適用したいです。
Railsのバージョンは7.0.6です。
解決策をお願いします。

一応application.cssの中身

[image: 一応application.cssの中身]

Comment: Rails のバージョンはいくつですか？　また、何でもよいのでスタイルが適用されていない HTML の中身をひとつ見せていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: railsのバージョンは7.0.6です。

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7.0 の場合、`rails new` した直後の状態では app/views/layouts/application.html.erb に `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>` のような記述が[あるはずです](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.tt)。`"data-turbo-track": "reload"` があるかどうかは Hotwire (Turbo) を使っているかで変わります。まずこれがあるかを確認してください。まったくスタイルが反映されないということであれば、application.css を読み込めていない可能性があります。

これがあるのにスタイルが反映されない場合、ブラウザで HTML ソースを見たときに application.css を読む `<style>` タグがあるか確認してください。これが無かったり、あっても CSS の内容がおかしい場合、何かしら設定がデフォルトから外れていてうまく動いていません。怪しいのはアセットパイプラインなので、設定やコマンドに間違いがないか確認してみてください: https://railsguides.jp/v7.0/asset_pipeline.html。

application.css を読み込んでいて、その中身も意図したものになっているのにスタイルが反映されない場合、HTML か CSS の実装がおかしいです。打ち間違いが無いかなどを確認してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
実はその後別の問題が発生しまして。。。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/96293/%e6%ad%a3%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%af%e3%81%9a%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab%e7%89%b9%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e3%82%84%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%a4%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c