# 正しいはずなのに特定のフォルダやファイルが赤くなってるのはなぜ？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

新しく作り直したやつ · Noob-9191/RAILS-dedicated-to-public@0a44837 (https://github.com/Noob-9191/RAILS-dedicated-to-public/commit/0a4483789f7de024d5b07770e8f183739b8b1419#diff-0d66e2f983c4dea8c01834cb9c053ceb740299be0f7663b806a524d8419bb9be)
ところどころ特定のフォルダやファイルが赤くなってますが、何が問題かわかりません。
VSCodeで開いても表示が赤くなっていて、どこが問題なのかさっぱりわかりません。

[image: なぜか赤くなってるフォルダやファイル]

VSCodeのWSLで `rails s` もできない状態です。

ChatGPTに頼っても全然解決できません。
いったい何が問題なのでしょうか？
どうか解決策をお願いします。

```
$ rails s

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options Exiting /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:209:in
`rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
(ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:186:in
`_decrypt'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:160:in
`decrypt_and_verify'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in
`decrypt_and_verify'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:104:in
`decrypt'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:66:in
`read'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:43:in
`read'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:64:in
`config'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:79:in
`options'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in
`method_missing'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:332:in
`block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
`instance_exec'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
`run'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in
`block in run_initializers'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block
in tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block
(2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in
`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block
in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in
`each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in
`tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in
`tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
`run_initializers'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in
`initialize!'
        from /mnt/c/Users/rii/proj/netlibx/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in
`eval'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in
`new_from_string'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in
`load_file'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in
`parse_file'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in
`build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in
`app'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in
`wrapped_app'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in
`log_to_stdout'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in
`start'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in
`block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in
`perform'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in
`dispatch'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in
`perform'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
`<main>'
        from <internal:/home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in
`require'
        from <internal:/home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in
`require'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in
`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>' <internal:pack>:309:in `unpack1': invalid base64 (ArgumentError)
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/base64.rb:74:in
`strict_decode64'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:188:in
`block in _decrypt'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:188:in
`map'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:188:in
`_decrypt'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:160:in
`decrypt_and_verify'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in
`decrypt_and_verify'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:104:in
`decrypt'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:66:in
`read'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:43:in
`read'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:64:in
`config'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:79:in
`options'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in
`method_missing'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:332:in
`block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
`instance_exec'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in
`run'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in
`block in run_initializers'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block
in tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block
(2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in
`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block
in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in
`each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in
`tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in
`tsort_each'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in
`run_initializers'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in
`initialize!'
        from /mnt/c/Users/rii/proj/netlibx/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in
`eval'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in
`new_from_string'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in
`load_file'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in
`parse_file'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in
`build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in
`app'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in
`wrapped_app'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in
`log_to_stdout'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in
`start'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in
`block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in
`perform'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
`invoke_command'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in
`dispatch'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in
`perform'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
`<main>'
        from <internal:/home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in
`require'
        from <internal:/home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in
`require'
        from /home/sora/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in
`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Git でソースコードを管理する過程で、「コンフリクト」が発生したままコミットしてしまっているようです。

bin/rails を例に取ると、以下のように `<<< HEAD` ～ `===` ～ `>>> a1cd10` で囲まれた部分があります。

> ```
> <<<<<<< HEAD
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
> =======
> #!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
> >>>>>>> a1cd101aa28f94b85a0f957bf4c5d154344698c3
> APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
> require_relative "../config/boot"
> require "rails/commands"
> ```

これは、ローカルと GitHub 上とのコミットで、同じ個所に異なる変更を行ってしまった際にどちらを優先すべきか自動では判別できない時に挿入されます。

コンフリクト (衝突) が発生した際は上記のようなマークを目安に、人間が自分の目で判断して正しいコードに修正したうえで改めてコミットする必要があります。

参考:
[第4話 コンフリクトは怖くない！解決方法【連載】マンガでわかるGit ～コマンド編～](https://www.r-staffing.co.jp/engineer/entry/20190927_1)

Comment: つまりgit上でrailsアプリフォルダをまたもう1回コミットすれば解決しますか？
一応vscode上では、アプリケーションフォルダ内のすべてのフォルダやファイル（赤くなってるやつ全部）のHEADの修正部分は現在のままにするっていう感じにはしました。

Comment: gitを開いてrailsアプリケーションフォルダに移動したらブランチ名が(main|MERGING)になってました。
これってどうすればいいですか？またコミットすればいいですか？